# Rails apartment with merit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, merit-gem, apartment-gem

I use the reputation engine Merit and I have added apartment for multitenancy. I want to exclude the merit models and tables.

the following line generates an error:

```
config.excluded_models= {Merit::Badge}
```

undefined method `table_name' for Merit::Badge(id, name, level, description, custom_fields)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `Merit::Badge` is an `Ambry` model (in memory), and not `ActiveRecord`. You don't need to define it as excluded model, but this means that every instance of your app needs to know all the badges as of now.